# Flattening an array in powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have some code that pulls from an API into a variable called `$table`.  I can export this variable to a csv with no issues, except the last field in the table (`$table.userdefinedfields`) exports as a `SystemObject[]`.

What I would like is a 3 column table consisting of the 1st and 3rd fields of `$table` and the 29th field of the `SystemObject[]`.

I am not too well versed in powershell, but this must be possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's possible. Could you edit your post to include the original result of the API call (sanitizing values as needed)?

Comment: Actually `SystemObject[]` means Array of Elements, CSV file can show only single string elements, the fast and easy solution is to join the Array elements with a comma (or any other character), for example `$table.userdefinedfields -join ","` and then export it again, if you need more precise solution, add your code to the question

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) with a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties):

```sh
$table | 
  Select-Object -ExcludeProperty userdefinedfields -Property *, @{
    Name = 'Field29' # change as needed
    Expression = { $_.userdefinedfields[28] }
  } # | Export-Csv ...
```

The above uses *all* original properties (`*`), *except* the `userdefinedfields` property, and adds a calculated property with self-chosen name `Field29` that contains the 29th element (`[28]`) of the array stored in each input object's `.userdefinedfields` property.

Since you only want a *subset* of the original properties, replace `*` with the property names of interest, i.e the names of the 1st and 3rd properties (e.g., `Foo, Bar`); you can then omit the `-ExcludeProperty` parameter.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @TomRepetti; my pleasure. Please allow me to give you the standard advice to newcomers in the next comment; please also consider revisiting your previous questions: